# Is it possible to blur part of image on touch in Android?

Tags: android, paint

i want to blur particular area on image view.

eg. i want to allow user to draw rectangle similar to crop in android, 
once user draws that rectangle on image, the area inside rectangle will be blurred
or on finger touch.

i searched a lot,but most of the examples explain how to blur full image,
dint find any tutorial or link that explains about blurring only some part
of an image.

any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Learn about how `View` and `Canvas` work.

Comment: i know about view and canvas,using both in my project. my problem is that i dont know how to blur only some part of canvas.

Comment: have to solved the problem? i need to do same thing

Comment: you need to take rectangle bounds and pass it to your bluring algorithm:)

Comment: have you solved prob? then plz help me i need the same thing

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing easier!

But you can only pixelate it, select the targeted area, press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) twice or thrice, then (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) the same number of times.