# Android gaussian blur on part of an image

Tags: android, android-canvas, blur, gaussian, renderscript

I am trying to implement a feature in the app that blurs some part of an image based on users selection/touch. I have suceessfully applied the Android's "RenderScript" method to blur full image however, I can't find an example of blurring only some part of an image.

If anyone can point me to a right direction, that would be great.

I used code from following question to achive full image blur.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21052060/1293053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paint and blur parts of your canvas. There are some links which can be help to you :

[Blur on touch. Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188079/blur-on-touch-android-application)

[Is it possible to blur part of image on touch in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844317/is-it-possible-to-blur-part-of-image-on-touch-in-android)

[Android draw with blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979955/android-draw-with-blur)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use forEach(Allocation aout, Script.LaunchOptions opt) of ScriptIntrinsicBlur with an appropriate opt value to set the rectangle you want to blur. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html has the description.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this library: https://github.com/jrvansuita/GaussianBlur

```
//Asynchronous with scaleDown and changing radius
GaussianBlur.with(context).size(300).radius(10).put(R.mipmap.your_image, imageView);
```